# Cannot add Style to Resourcedictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm getting following error when try to add style to Resourcedictionary.

```
cannot add content of type 'system.windows.style' to an object of type 'system.windows.resourcedictionary'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due duplicate keys. Finaly found another style added with same key.